# The URL that should display a Google Sheet data in JSON format shows internal error

Tags: laravel, google-sheets

I want to convert the data of a Google Sheet into JSON format so that I can use it on my website. However, I get a 500 error whenever the website tries to fetch the JSON file.

I have already tried different methods to convert my sheet into JSON that are available on the internet

```
$url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1dpmzzKNR8hRILX6qMD0KTruxxXYT3UAXR0EcX0zS0dE/1/public/full?alt=json';
$file= file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($file);
$rows = $json->{'feed'}->{'entry'};
return $rows;
```

Comment: There's an issue logged on Google's bug tracker - it's worth following the issue there to see if there's any resolution: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131613284

Comment: Had the same issue today, it doesn't appear that we can do anything about it yet. Your code is most likely fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; I was able to work around the problem by parsing the html from the pubhtml page directly to output a similar JSON format:

Instead of using the Google Sheet ID, use the link for "Publish to Webpage".

There are some rows that I skip since some are for frozen rows, but you should be able to modify the code to your needs.

```
function importGoogleSheets(publishedUrl, sheetId, onSuccess, onError) {

        var headers = [];
        var rows;

        $.ajax({
            url: publishedUrl+'?gid='+sheetId+'&single=true',
            success: function(data) {
                data = $.parseHTML(data)[5];
                htmldata = data;
                rows = data.getElementsByTagName('tr');

                for (var i = 0; i < rows[1].cells.length; i++) {
                    headers[i] = 'gsx$' + rows[1].cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/[^0-9a-z]*/g, '');
                }

                for (var i = 3; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    temp = {};
                    for (var h = 1; h < headers.length; h++) {
                        temp[headers[h]] = {'$t': rows[i].cells[h].textContent};
                    }
                    all_data[i - 3] = temp;
                }
                onSuccess(all_data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                onError(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

One note though is that it includes any empty rows unlike the feed, so you may want to filter the ouptut based on some column.